# Unique length-3 palindromes python

Tags: python, palindrome

i have this problem where you have to find all **length three**  palindromes and print how many there are.

For example:

```
aabca
```

Output:

```
3
aba
aaa
aca
```

I already know how to get the num for how many there are with the code i found on the web below:

```
res = 0
unq_str = set(s)
for ch in unq_str:
    st = s.find(ch)
    ed = s.rfind(ch)
    if st<ed:
        res+=len(set(s[st+1:ed]))

return res
```

but thats only for the num

so i tried on the concept where you iterate through it and take lists with
length three and check if it is a palindrome

```
for x in range(len(input1)):
    if not x < 3:
        Str1 = input1[x-3:x]
```

but then i stopped because it doesn't go for any kind of combination

is there any way to do this?

thanks

Comment: Your code only looks for contiguous substrings. Your sample output has `aaa`, which isn't contiguous.

Comment: @Barmar so, what should i do?

Comment: Iterate through the string to get the first character of the palindrome. Then check if there's a matching character later in the string. You can then form a palindrome from those 2 characters and each of the characters between them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure this is correct but hopefully it will put you on the correct track.

```
import itertools

input = "aabca"
palindromes = set() # use a set to ensure no duplicates

# iterate over all combinates of length 3
for t in itertools.combinations(input, 3):
    # is this a palindrome? If so save
    if t == tuple(reversed(t)):
        palindromes.add(''.join(t))

# output results
print(palindromes)
print(len(palindromes))
```

There may be an itertools recipe which doesn't generate duplicates but I think this works.

Edit: Using join results in a set of strings rather than string characters.

Edit2: To make this equivalent to keithpjolly's answer:

```
import itertools

input = "aabca"
palindromes = set() # use a set to ensure no duplicates

# iterate over all combinates of length 3
for a,b,c in itertools.combinations(input, 3):
    # is this a palindrome? If so save
    if a == c:
        palindromes.add(''.join((a,b,c)))


# output results
print(palindromes)
print(len(palindromes))
```

Answer (score 5):

How about:

```
from itertools import combinations
s = 'aabca'
p = set([''.join([a,b,c]) for a,b,c in combinations(s, 3) if a == c])
print(p)
print(len(p))
```

Ouput:

```
{'aaa', 'aba', 'aca'}
3
```

Edit - `combinations` much better than `permutations`.
Edit - Forgot about the `length`.

Comment: Nice and clean, I like it! It's worth studying both this and my answer to understand what's going on. In mine the steps are split out, this is a really nice way to combine them into a single expression.

Comment: For three letter anagrams I'd stick with my way but if the assignment was for N-letters then yours would be the way to go for sure.